# converting edgelist data to networkx object

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a file which looks like-

```
1 2 1
1 3 1
2 999 1
2 1029 1
2 1031 1
2 1032 1
2 1197 1
2 1226 1
2 1296 1
3 450 1
3 933 1
3 934 1
3 955 1
3 1032 1
4 5 1
```

and I want to convert it to networkx graph but I am getting the following error-

```
   G=nx.read_edgelist(fh)
  File "<decorator-gen-400>", line 2, in read_edgelist
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 227, in _open_file
    result = func_to_be_decorated(*new_args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\edgelist.py", line 378, in read_edgelist
    data=data)
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\edgelist.py", line 288, in parse_edgelist
    "Failed to convert edge data (%s) to dictionary." % (d))
TypeError: Failed to convert edge data (['1']) to dictionary.
```

and here is the code-

```
fh=open("YST_full.net", 'rb')
G=nx.read_edgelist(fh)
fh.close()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

edit-I tried converting it to pandas dataframe

```
df=pd.read_csv("YST_full.net",sep=" ",names=['node1','node2','weight'])
print(df)

G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'node1', 'node2', ['weight'])
```

and now I want to convert it to graphml format-

```
nx.write_graphml(G, "YST_full.graphml")
```

but the error is-

```
    nx.write_graphml(G, "YST_full.graphml")
  File "<decorator-gen-440>", line 2, in write_graphml_lxml
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 227, in _open_file
    result = func_to_be_decorated(*new_args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py", line 149, in write_graphml_lxml
    infer_numeric_types=infer_numeric_types)
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py", line 596, in __init__
    self.add_graph_element(graph)
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\graphml.py", line 658, in add_graph_element
    T = self.xml_type[self.attr_type(k, "edge", v)]
KeyError: <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must inform `networkx` that the third column is an attribute called "weight" (or whatever you call it):

```
graph = nx.read_edgelist("YST_full.net", data=(('weight', float),))
```

As far as your second question is concerned, sometimes `networkx` fails to convert a NumPy `int64` to the Python `int` before exporting to GraphML. You have to do it yourself:

```
weights = {(n1,n2): float(d['weight']) # or int()
                    for n1,n2,d in graph.edges(data=True)}
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, weights, 'weight')
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I started learning network analysis and this is the first error I encountered. I just changed `G=nx.read_edgelist(fh)` to `G=nx.read_weighted_edgelist(fh)`.

You can also remove the third column and use `G=nx.read_edgelist(fh)`

Answer (score 0):

If you do change `G=nx.read_edgelist(fh)` to `G=nx.read_weighted_edgelist(fh)`, it will work.

You don't need to remove third column. I am using **SNAP Temporal data** for `node2vec` project, was facing same error as described, solving by using  `G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(args.input, nodetype=int, data=(('weight',float),),delimiter=',', create_using=nx.DiGraph())`